# change values of multiple columns meeting criteria

Tags: r

I have a df with numeric data, which are dummies for factor type data and I want to change the maximum value into 0 so I can create a correlation table and regression models avoiding perfect multicollinearity.

I came out with the solution bellow but the output is an error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, a, i, value = 0) :
  duplicate subscripts for columns
```

the code is:

```
  data <- data.frame(
  a = runif(n=10,min=1,max=10),
  b = runif(n=10,min=1,max=3),
  c = runif(n=10,min=1,max=6)
)

for(col in data){
  for(v in col){
    if(v == max(col)){
      data[v,col] <- 0
    }
  }
}
```

what is wrong and how to correct?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `col` is a vector, i.e. a column of your dataset, not a column name or index. That's why you get an error when doing `data[v,col] <- 0`. However, the second `for` is not really needed.

Instead you could do:

```r
set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(
  a = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
  b = sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
  c = sample(1:6, 10, replace = TRUE)
)

for(col in names(data)) {
  v <- data[[col]]
  data[v == max(v), col] <- 0
}

data
#>    a b c
#> 1  3 0 2
#> 2  3 1 1
#> 3  0 0 0
#> 4  2 0 3
#> 5  6 1 4
#> 6  5 1 0
#> 7  4 1 1
#> 8  6 1 3
#> 9  9 0 5
#> 10 0 2 4
```

Or using `lapply` instead of a `for` loop:

```
data[] <- lapply(data, function(x) { x[x == max(x)] <- 0; x })

data
#>    a b c
#> 1  3 0 2
#> 2  3 1 1
#> 3  0 0 0
#> 4  2 0 3
#> 5  6 1 4
#> 6  5 1 0
#> 7  4 1 1
#> 8  6 1 3
#> 9  9 0 5
#> 10 0 2 4
```